# Knitr error: Error in .External2(C_X11, paste("png::", filename, sep = ""), g$width, : unable to start device PN

Tags: r, png, knitr

Something similar to this question has been asked before but the answer might not apply in my case.

I am getting the following error after trying to "knit" a document:

```
Quitting from lines 30-34 (test.Rnw)
Error in .External2(C_X11, paste("png::", filename, sep = ""), g$width,  :
  unable to start device PNG
In addition: Warning message:
In (function (filename = "Rplot%03d.png", width = 480, height = 480,  :
  unable to open connection to X11 display '
```

It just happens with the following:

<>=
    library(lattice)
    bitmap('test.png')
    xyplot(1:2~1:2)
    dev.off()
@

The system that I am running this in does not have X11 installed.  Is that absolutely necessary??  This seems to be what is required (according to my online research) but I was hoping not to have to do it as this is a production machine and I wanted to keep it as "lean" as possible. 
Thank you very much for any help. 
Ramiro

Comment: For the record: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.r.general/322946

Comment: Thank you so much.  That is the answer.

Comment: @Yihui the link to gmane is dead, and unfortunately that was where the answer was...

Comment: I probably meant http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Error-in-External2-C-X11-paste-png-filename-sep-g-width-unable-to-start-device-PNG-tp4710983.html